# Can I do an 'in' search with searchlogic/metasearch in Rails 3 passing an array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, searchlogic

I am using the acts_as_network gem which allows me to get all the friends for a User through 'User.friends'

I want to create a 'friend feed' showing all the recent events for all of the friends by searching through the Event records where Event:

```
  Event  | giver_id | receiver_id | date |
```

**Conceptually** I'd like to be able to do this:

```
feed = Events.giver_id_or_receiver_id_in(User.friends).date_gt(Date.today.2.weeks.ago)
```

This should give me an array of all events where either the giver_id or receiver_id is IN the array of friends (User.friends), created in the last two weeks.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

IN queries can be done with:  where(:giver_id => array)

So I think you can do something like:

```
scope :party_in, lambda {|friends| where(:giver_id => friends) | where(:receiver_id => friend) }
```

You can then chain the scope with the rest of your query:

```
feed = Events.party_in(User.friends).date_gt(Date.today.2.weeks.ago)
```

Comment: is this using metawhere instead of rd_searchlogic?  And I use 'friend' or 'friends'?  tx

Comment: btw, User.friends isn't an array of *just* ID's (e.g. ["1", "2", "3"]) it is the array representing actual Users....

Comment: Oh, yeah, that's metawhere, sorry. If User.friends doesn't automatically call to_param on it, you could do User.friends.map(&:id)